# Script works in browser only when I hit F5

Tags: php

My script works in the browser only when I hit F5. The previous result seem to be cached or something.

This is how it looks like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/unsubscribe.php
```

This causes a serious problem. I have an unsubscribe link in my email I want send out to users but when I click it, nothing happens, because the click is considered the same when I hit enter in the browser. So even though I have a parameter in the link as

```
http://mywebsite.com/unsubscribe.php?email=tom@gmail.com
```

the value is not captured.

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$newsletter = 'No';


    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET NEWSLETTER = ? WHERE EMAIL = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($newsletter, $email));
        $response["success"] = 1;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }
    echo 'email: '.$email.'<br>';
    print(json_encode($response));
```

Result:

```
email: tom@gmail.com
{"success":1}
```

But this is because tom@gmail.com is cached (or something else) but the value is not updated in the database.
Now when I hit F5, the value is updated in the database. What's wrong?

Comment: You never initialize `$response` as an array. You use GET variables without checking that they are set. And finally, printing stuff before the JSON makes it useless.

Comment: I don't think that matters. This is a sample code and I know that I can't echo anything before printing json but I am currently testing in the browser. Even though I add a simple echo 'X' before everything, it doesn't get printed out unless I hit F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the cache, you should add some headers to remove the cache. Then, you should send a whole valid JSON! (You added unvalid part with some text).

headers:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');//*/
```

[Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) -If you use this method, it automatically sends headers-

```
include('includes/json.php');

$Json = new json();

$email = $_GET['email'];
$newsletter = 'No';
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET NEWSLETTER = ? WHERE EMAIL = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($newsletter, $email));
    $response["success"] = 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
}

$Json->add('status', '200');
$Json->add('message', '$success');
$Json->add('email', '$email');
$Json->add('response', '$response');

$Json->send();
```

Comment: I used only the cache-control and expires headers and now it works in Firefox. I am still working on why Chrome handles this differently. Thanks

Comment: Maybe cleaning the cache of chrome would do the job. Maybe chrome stores "That webstite accept cache" ? I do not really know. :/